# Can I test a RecyclerView in Espresso without an Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

**The Test** - I have an Espresso test suite designed to test some complex decision making with a RecyclerView adapter.

For one test I intend to create a RecyclerView, pass it the adapter under test and then determine that the correct number of children exist, with the correct elements being visible.

**The problem** - I am testing this in isolation without a specific Activity, which means that the following code never passes, because the RecyclerView never lays out its children:

```
RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
rv.setAdapter(adap);
assertThat(rv.getChildCount(), is(greaterThan(0)));
```

I assume I could make this work by creating an empty activity and an empty layout with the RecyclerView in, but i want to avoid creating garbage classes like that.

**The Question** - Is it possible to get the RecyclerView to function alone like this? Does Espresso have some root view I can access to attach it to?

Comment: You could try calling `measure()` and `layout()` on the `RecyclerView` directly, and see if that's sufficient to get it to do what you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've actually tried `measure(View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)` and `layout(0,0, rv.getHeight(), rv.getWidth())` together but this didn't achieve anything

Comment: I'd use concrete values (e.g., height of 800, width of 480), though that may not help. It works with basic layouts (e.g., `LinearLayout`), but I have never tried this with a `RecyclerView`. You might also need to idle between the `measure()`/`layout()` calls and checking the `RecyclerView`, as `RecyclerView` might be `post()`-ing some work or otherwise requiring a few passes through the main `Looper` before it is done. In the end, you may wind up having to just test your `RecyclerView.Adapter` directly, rather than testing `RecyclerView` that happens to use your adapter.

Comment: Thanks. You were correct, a fixed size worked. I am still unable to `perform(click())` without an activity, but I think that is a separate issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), the way to ensure RecyclerView is ready for testing without an activity is to force layout yourself.

```
RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()));
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
rv.measure(View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
rv.layout(0,0, 800, 480); //arbitrary sizes
```

After creating your view in this manner, the child count will no longer be zero

```
assertThat(rv.getChildCount(), is(greaterThan(0)));
```

The one caveat to testing the RecyclerView without an Activity is you are unable to perform actions.

```
onView(...).perform(click());
```

Without an activity this code will throw a RuntimeException with the message

> No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?